# how to send email from DSL job after create new pipeline job is successul or fail

Tags: email, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I want to send email after finish create pipeline job from dsl build.
When using extendedEmail plugin show publishers error when search publishers can use only freejob.
So please someone can answer me what kind of plugin or ways to send email from DSl

```
pipelineJob("${JobName}") {
     definition {
           cps {
             script('''
                
            pipeline {
                agent any
                stages {
                    stage('deploy') {

                        steps {
                          echo "Test"
                        }
                     }
                  } }
'''.stripIndent())
       sandbox()
          }
      }
  // here i want send email finish create pipeline job //
 
}
Thank you
```

Comment: You should add an email step it in the Job itself (the job that runs the DSL) and not inside the DSL code.

Comment: @NoamHelmer please can u show some sample ... Thank u

Comment: In the Jenkins UI job in which you configured you DSL by using the "Process Job DSLs" build step, you can add more build steps or post build steps like email sending that you want. First locate that job configure it and add the steps you need. You can take a look at [This Guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-automate-jenkins-job-configuration-using-job-dsl) for creating that job and see how to configure it.